# Tensorflow green-shifts image

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def load(im1, im2):
    ima1 = tf.io.read_file(im1)
    ima1 = tf.image.decode_image(ima1)
    ima1 = tf.cast(ima1, tf.float32)

    ima2 = tf.io.read_file(im2)
    ima2 = tf.image.decode_image(ima2)
    ima2 = tf.cast(ima2, tf.float32)

    return ima1, ima2

inp, re = load(r"RAWs/1313 (1).jpg", r"Clean/1313 (1).png")

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(inp)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(re)
plt.show()
```

Everything works fine, no errors, except that the second image `re` is greenshifted (right-most image below):

[image]

I have the latest version of tensorflow-cpu as I don't have a GPU due to current shortage, Python 3.9 64 Bit.

Does someone know why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Raw images: [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Od3.png), [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtjms.png), [three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FObZi.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a colour image, it's a single-channel greyscale image. You are looking at [**false colour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_color), sometimes called **pseudocolour**. The `imshow()` function is mapping the numbers in the array to the colours in the `viridis` colourmap.

Colour images have 3 channels (or 4, if they have opacity too). So a NumPy array of a colour image will have shape like `(h, w, 3)` or `(h, w, 4)`. This one has a single channel (shape like `(h, w)`). To put it another way, it's a greyscale image.

If you plot this array with `plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')` it will display how you're expecting. This scheme maps zeros (or whatever the lowest number is) to black and ones (or the highest value) to white. (See all `maplotlib`'s colourmaps [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html).)